# Error in resource configuration while using $resource.query() function with AngularJS/Rails

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to add it to one of my Rails projects. I'm using the angular-rails gem. I want to list users using $resource.query() and I'm getting the following error:

> Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object

When I check localhost:3000/users.json it's showing an array of user objects, so the response should be in the correct format. Here's what I have:

In app/assets/javascript/users.js.coffee:

```
app = angular.module("Volunteers", ["ngResource"])

app.factory "User", ["$resource", ($resource) ->
  $resource("/users/:id", {id: "@id"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}})
]

@UserCtrl = ["$scope", "User", ($scope, User) ->
  $scope.users = User.query()
]
```

In app/views/users/index.html:

```
<div ng-controller="UserCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users">
      {{user.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And in the users_controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json, :html 

    def index
        respond_with User.all
    end
```

Comment: Well, after looking a little longer I found that adding .json in the resource url parameter fixes the problem: 
    $resource("/users/:id.json", {id: "@id"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.factory "User", ["$resource", ($resource) ->
$resource("/users/:id.json", {id: "@id"}, {query: {method: "PUT"}})
]
```

Did you mistype 'query' to 'update'?

If what you get is array, you should set isArray=true, else set it false, same as the guy said above me.

Answer (score 3):

Add **isArray:false** to resource declaration, for example:

```
'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false }
```