# Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object

Tags: angularjs

I am a complete noob with respect to angular, just going through a codeschool tutorial and I've hit my first hurdle.

I am getting `Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object`

Here is my code:

```
var bulletinApp = angular.module('bulletinApp', ['ngResource']);

bulletinApp.controller('PostsController', ['$scope', 'Post', function($scope, Post) {
    $scope.heading = 'Welcome';
    $scope.posts = Post.query();

    $scope.newPost = {
        title: 'Test Post'
    }

}]);

bulletinApp.factory('Post', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/posts');
}]);
```

I found an answer here:
[Error in resource configuration while using $resource.query() function with AngularJS/Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037852/error-in-resource-configuration-while-using-resource-query-function-with-angu)

That says I should add this to my resource declaration:

```
'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false }
```

Problem being I have no idea where I am supposed to add this, or even if this is the problem I'm having?

EDIT:

```
bulletinApp.factory('Post', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/posts', {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false}});
}]);
```

After this I am still receiving the error. Also in the tutorial, there was no need for this and I've followed it pretty much to a tee, why would the get method be getting an object instead of an array?

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

Comment: Thanks, was just reading it, reckon you could check my edit to see if I have added it correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular Js. How fix Error: \[$resource:badcfg\] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041306/angular-js-how-fix-error-resourcebadcfg-error-in-resource-configuration-e)

Answer (score 16):

Add `{}` after `'/posts'`.

```
bulletinApp.factory('Post', ['$resource', function($resource) { 
    return $resource('/posts', {}, {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false}}); 
}]);
```

For details, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041306/angular-js-how-fix-error-resourcebadcfg-error-in-resource-configuration-e).

Answer (score 6):

The result of 'Get' is array or just object?  If it's an array, set isArray=true, else set isArray=false, like the guy said above

```
bulletinApp.factory('Post', ['$resource', function($resource) { 
return $resource('/posts', {}, {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false/*true*/}}); 
}]);
```

And attention IsArray is different with isArray.
Or if you got your data by json, please add ***.json as url

Answer (score 0):

The next line of the error message in the console is a url to a fuller description of the error:

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an object but got an array
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$resource/badcfg?p0=object&p1=array
```

According to the [linked page](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$resource/badcfg?p0=object&p1=array) either your server's not returning what you think it is or you need to tell $resource to expect an array from the server.